# GTA V's latest update has introduced a lot of lag - can this be fixed?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, grand-theft-auto-v

After Rockstar deployed a new update, GTA V on PC has become extremely laggy and can't be played.

Can this be solved?

Comment: you should add extra info as: version of the game, specs of your PC, what is exactly happening in-game, etc... and sources you saw / things you tried to solve it

Comment: V4karian is right. It could either be a hardware or software related issue.

Answer (score 1):

It started with the last update, quite a few people have it. Rockstar support have told people it's windows 10's fault. Some people can fix it by removing their Social Club folder.

There currently doesn't seem to be a fix that works for me but you can try:

- Removing your 'Social Club' folder.
- Run under Compatibility mode for Windows 7/8
- Different drivers new/old.
- Various NVIDIA Control panel settings.
- Monitoring CPU/GPU usage (It drops significantly during the freezing)
- Taking back my GPU/CPU overclock (Ik it's stable, I was just desperate :P)

Comment: What source do you have for this being Window 10's fault?